# JavaFX 8: TableView Filtering & Row Removal

Tags: model-view-controller, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

Please pardon the chunk of codes below, i'm presenting them for clarity. Thanks!

I have a table view control [suiteCasesSelected] of type [TestSuiteDetail] that has the following functions:

filter function that I got from this tutorial: [JavaFX 8 TableView Sorting and Filtering](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/)

```
//Triggered every time I type something on the filter box
private void filterTestSuiteSelectedList() {
    // Wrap the ObservableList in a FilteredList (display all data).
    FilteredList<TestSuiteDetail> filteredData = new FilteredList<>(mainApp.getTestSuiteSelectedData(), p -> true);

    // Set the filter Predicate whenever the filter changes.
    suiteSelectedFilter.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        filteredData.setPredicate(tc -> {
            // Display all if filter is empty
            if (newValue == null || newValue.isEmpty()) {
                return true;
            }
            // Compare test case name or module name
            String lowerCaseFilter = newValue.toLowerCase();
            if (tc.getTestCaseName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true;
            } else if (tc.getModuleName().toLowerCase().contains(lowerCaseFilter)) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    });

    // Wrap the FilteredList in a SortedList.
    SortedList<TestSuiteDetail> sortedData = new SortedList<>(filteredData);

    // Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(suiteCasesSelected.comparatorProperty());

    // Add sorted and filtered data to the table.
    suiteCasesSelected.setItems(sortedData);
}
```

remove items from the list via button press:

```
@FXML
private void handleRemoveFromSelectedClicked() {
    ObservableList selectedItems = suiteCasesSelected.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();
    if (selectedItems != null) {
        suiteCasesSelected.getItems().removeAll(selectedItems);
        mainApp.saveSuiteDetailsSelectedXMLData(testSuite);
        TestNGXmlConverter.updateTestSuiteXMLFile(testSuite.getTestSuiteName());
    }
}
```

**My problem:**
Every time I select items from the table and click the remove '<<' button, I get multiple exceptions starting from

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

and finally ending at

```
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
at java.util.AbstractList.remove(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source)
at java.util.AbstractCollection.removeAll(Unknown Source)
at cl.oe.beatrix.view.ControllerWindowMain.handleRemoveFromSelectedClicked(ControllerWindowMain.java:2043)
... 70 more
```

Line 2043 points to `suiteCasesSelected.getItems().removeAll(selectedItems);` presented above.

**Additional Info:**

I'm calling the entire filter method `filterTestSuiteSelectedList()` on the `initialize()` method of the controller class.

The exception only happens if I put in the filter function in place. It works fine if I comment it out.

Appreciate the help! Please do let me know if further information is needed!

[Table snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5kOj.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to solve this problem.

A user encountered a similar problem and posted it in the tutorials [See the comments all the way below the blog post](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/).

Raw:

```
// The index of the sorted and filtered list.
int visibleIndex = personTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

// Source index of master data.
int sourceIndex = sortedData.getSourceIndexFor(masterData, visibleIndex);

// Remove.
masterData.remove(sourceIndex);
```

Modified for my case (multiple selection table):

```
@FXML
private void handleRemoveFromSelectedClicked() {
    // Get all the selected items
    ObservableList<Integer> selectedItems = suiteCasesSelected.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices();
    if (selectedItems != null) {
        // Iterate through each item
        for (Integer selectedItem : selectedItems) {
            int sourceIndex = filteredSelectedData.getSourceIndexFor(mainApp.getTestSuiteSelectedData(),
                    selectedItem.intValue());
            //remove        
            mainApp.getTestSuiteSelectedData().remove(sourceIndex);
        }

        mainApp.saveSuiteDetailsSelectedXMLData(testSuite);
        TestNGXmlConverter.updateTestSuiteXMLFile(testSuite.getTestSuiteName());
    }
}
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Since `FilteredList` and `SortedList` are just views of a list, they are not modifiable; items can only be removed by modifying the backing list:

```
ObservableList<TestSuiteDetail> modifiableSource = ...

FilteredList<TestSuiteDetail> filteredList = new FilteredList<(modifiableSource);
SortedList<TestSuiteDetail> sortedList = new SortedList<>(filteredList);

...

modifiableSource.removeAll(selectedItems);
```

**BTW:** You do not need the to check the result of `suiteCasesSelected.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems()` for `null`, since this always returns a `List`, but this `List` may be empty...